# creating a 32 bit wineprefix on 64bit system?

Tags: wine, 64-bit

I saw there are similar questions but none helped.

I tried to follow the instructions I found at [WineHQ](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#32_bit_wineprefix):

```
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=/path/to/wineprefix winecfg
```

Can you tell me what 'path to wineprefix' means? I don't understand and don't want to make a mistake.

**Edit:**

So, my `.wine/drive_c` is my wineprefix?

If so, then, is this the command I need to run?

```
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=/home/myname/.wine/drive_c winecfg`
```

Comment: For the record, when you are requesting additional information you can add a comment to an answer.  That way, the poster of the answer sees your message.  To answer your question, it might be there, yes, you have to make sure that that path actually exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it's asking for is the path to your virtual C: drive, which is called your 'wine prefix'.

When they specifically say the path to the wine prefix, they want the full path to where your virtual C: drive is.  To that end, the same FAQ you're looking at explains what your WinePrefix is, and what the default wineprefix location is:

> **1.9. Where is my C: drive?**
>
> Wine uses a virtual C: drive instead of your real C: drive. The
>   directory in which this is located is called a ***'wineprefix.'***
>
> By default, it's in your home directory's `.wine/drive_c` subdirectory.
>   (On MacOSX, see the MacOSX Wine FAQ for how to find this.)
>
> See also the `WINEPREFIX` environment variable; if this is set, wine
>   uses it to find the wineprefix.

<sub>[source](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-ac3550b8d9194ad164b9770742fcaafe91a891d6)</sub>

Comment: thank you for your answer,so my .wine/drive_c is my wineprefix? so it's WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=/home/myname/.wine/drive_c winecfg what i need to run?

Comment: @user169029 as i said in my other comment, that's the default wineprefix directory.  As I do not use Wine, any statements are going to be me guessing as to what the actual path is.  I would start by going and checking to see if that path (`/home/myname/.wine/drive_c`) exists, first, and if it does that's likely your wineprefix.  I'd make a backup of that directory first in case this breaks.